# Filter on parts of words in Matlab tables

Tags: matlab

Similar to Excel, I need to find out how to filter out rows of a table that do not contain a certain string.

For example, I need only rows that contain the letters "MX". Within the sheet, there are rows with strings like ZMX01, MX002, and US001. I would want the first two rows.

This seems like a simple question, so I am surprised I couldn't find any help for this!

It is similar to the question [Filter on words in Matlab tables (as in Excel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28463921/filter-on-words-in-matlab-tables-as-in-excel)

Comment: did you look at http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/dataset-array-rows.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com (I googled the search phrase "matlab select")

Comment: Are you filtering data from a text file, or have you loaded the data into the MATLAB workspace?

Answer (score 1):

You may not find a lot of information on tables in MATLAB, as they were introduced with version R2013a, which is not *that* long ago. So, about your question: Let's first create a sample table:

```
% Create a sample table
col1 = {'ZMX01'; 'MX002'; 'US001'};
col2 = {5;7;3};
T = table(col1, col2);

T = 
     col1      col2
    _______    ____

    'ZMX01'    [5] 
    'MX002'    [7] 
    'US001'    [3]
```

Now, MATLAB provides the [`rowfun`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rowfun.html) function to apply any function to each row in a table. By default, the function you call has to be able to work on *all* columns of the table.
To only apply `rowfun` to one column, you can use the `'InputVariables'` parameter, which lets you specify either the number of the column (e.g. `2` for the second column) or the name of the column (e.g. `'myColumnName'`).
Then, you can set `'OutputFormat'` to `'uniform'` to get an array and not a new table as output.

In your case, you'll want to use [`strfind`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) on the column `'col1'`. The return value of `strfind` is either an empty array (if `'MX'` wasn't found), or an array of all indices where `'MX'` was found.

```
% Apply rowfun
idx = rowfun(@(x)strfind(x,'MX'), T, 'InputVariables', 'col1', 'OutputFormat', 'uniform');
```

The output of this will be

```
idx = 
    [2]
    [1]
    []
```

i.e. a *3-by-1* cell array, which is empty for `'US001'` and contains a positive value for both other inputs. To create a subset of the table with this data, we can do the following:

```
% Create logical array, which is true for all rows to keep.
idx = ~cellfun(@isempty, idx);

% Save these rows and all columns of the table into a new table
R = T(idx,:);
```

And finally, we have our resulting table `R`:

```
R = 
     col1      col2
    _______    ____

    'ZMX01'    [5] 
    'MX002'    [7]
```

Comment: Is the overhead of `rowfun` really necessary here? You obtain the same `idx` with `idx = strfind(T.col1, 'MX');`

Comment: @excaza yes, you do get the same with `strfind`, so the overhead is not really necessary here. `rowfun` is especially useful for more complicated cases with multiple rows, or to directly create new columns with the results.